# Data Cache Problem

Tags: jquery

Facing one major problem related to cache.

I have User Creation form in that , if i put value which is already used in textfield then it does not shows "Check Availability" hyper link. but if i put new text then it show hyper link on change of textfield value event.

Code is written in Jquery. I think it's issue of data cache .What is the solution.

If i clear all data from Tool >> Internet Option then it works fine first time 
Here is the code

```
$('#userName').change(function(){
        if($('#userName').val()!= BLANK_STRING){            
            $('#checkUser').show();         
        }else{
            $('#checkUser').hide(); 
        }   
        $('#avilabilityMsg').html(''); 
    });
```

Please help?

Comment: Question updated please check

Comment: why not bind the `focus` event instead of `change`?

Comment: after binding with focus event , when i click using mouse huper link display but using tab its not working

Answer (score -1):

This might be best suited for the keyup event.

```
$(function(){
  var userName=$('#userName'), checkUser=$('#checkUser');
  userName.keyup(function(e){
    checkUser[($(this).val()===BLANK_STRING ? 'hide' : 'show')]();
  });
});
```

Comment: sorry it will fire every time on keyup event.